# Variable loses its assigned value

Tags: javascript

I am experimenting with the facebook API to retrieve information about events.

I made functions to retrieve the event's name, date, location, ...
But i'm struggling to return the event information from it's function correctly.

```
function retrieveEventName(eventID) {
    var name = "test";

    FB.api(eventID, // Make the API call
      function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
          name = response.name;
          // name = correct name of the event (NOT "test" any more!)
        }
      }
    );

    // name = test   "name" lost it's event name and is "test" again, WHY?
    return name; // returns "test" instead of the event's name...
}
```

I must be missing something elementary about javascript, but I was not able to find what is causing this problem (I presume a problem with scopes (caused by the nested function in the API call) but could not find any information about JS scopes that would explain the problem).

Note that i am sure that `name` is the name of the event when i'm in the `if` clause (I printed it to test it).

Comment: Yes, you are missing something elementary, *asynchronity*...

Comment: The Facebook API call is **asynchronous**. The callback is invoked when the operation completes, but the API call itself returns immediately. You can't use a `return` like that to get the value back.

Comment: So we're saying it's asynchronous?

Comment: Oh dear! Thanks guys, that indeed explains this behaviour :)

Comment: it's asynchronous... sorry had to say it :D

Comment: Man these comments were sure not synchronous.